# jQuery UI price range slider handling decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the price range slider from jQuery UI and echo some values in my config code. It all works except the highest price is not displayed correctly. When I echo both php variables this is what I see:

```
29.95
45
```

But in the price range slider the following values are displayed:

```
29.95 - 44.95
```

When I change the lowest value to be `30` it displays the highest value correctly (`45`), so the decimals are breaking this somehow. What can I do to fix that?

```js
// Price filter
$("#price-slider").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 29.95,
  max: 45,
  values: [29.95, 45],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#min-price").val('€' + ui.values[0]);
    $("#max-price").val('€' + ui.values[1]);
  }
});

$("#min-price").val('€' + $("#price-slider").slider("values", 0));
$("#max-price").val('€' + $("#price-slider").slider("values", 1));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="price-slider"></div>
<input id="min-price" />
<input id="max-price" />
```

Comment: Is that value in PHP coming from MySQL?

Comment: As the PHP is irrelevant to the problem could you please edit the question to include the actual output values. A working MCVE would be helpful too

Comment: @MasoodAslami Yes I retrieve it from my database, but I don't think it is a PHP issue because when I echo the values they are displayed correctly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've added the output.

Comment: Thank you for editing. I placed the code in an executable snippet - note that your code set the value to `45`, did you mean to use `44.95` instead?

Comment: Use jquery function toFixed(0) it may help to format decimal number.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No `45` is what I want, the problem is that it sets it to `44.95`

Comment: Ok - I'm just a little confused then as the example doesn't appear to do that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The slider itself showed `44.95` but in the code it displayed as `45`. Below answer fixed the issue.

Comment: That's my point - the example above shows `45` in the slider, but at least the answer below worked for whatever issue you had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding [step](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step) option

```
step: 0.01
```

The problem occurs because step **defaults to 1**

```js
$("#price-slider").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 29.95,
  max: 45,
  step: 0.01,
  values: [29.95, 45],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#min-price").val('€' + ui.values[0]);
    $("#max-price").val('€' + ui.values[1]);
  }
});
$("#min-price").val('€' + $("#price-slider").slider("values", 0));
$("#max-price").val('€' + $("#price-slider").slider("values", 1));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="price-slider" class="slide"></div>
<input id="min-price">
<input id="max-price">
```